# Pass value from child React context to parent React context

Tags: reactjs, react-context

I have 2 React context providers, both of which contain actions functions that update their state. I need to call one of these action function from the parent react context, but the context is undefined because it's not wrapped by the provider.

I cannot change the order of the wrapped providers. I also cannot put all the code inside the same provider (the code would be too large and not separated by concern).

```js
import React, {useContext, createContext} from 'react'

const AAAAContext = createContext()
const BBBBContext = createContext()

function AAAAProvider(props) {
  const bbbbContext = useContext(BBBBContext) // this is always undefined because not wrapped in BBBBProvider
  const aaaaActions = {
    doSomething: () => {
      bbbbContext.bbbbActions.doSomething()
    }
  }
  const aaaaContext = {aaaaActions}
  return <AAAAContext.Provider value={aaaaContext}>{props.children}</AAAAContext.Provider>
}

function BBBBProvider(props) {
  const aaaaContext = useContext(AAAAContext)
  const bbbbActions = {
    doSomething: () => {
      aaaaContext.aaaaActions.doSomething()
    }
  }
  const bbbbContext = {bbbbActions}
  return <BBBBContext.Provider value={bbbbContext}>{props.children}</BBBBContext.Provider>
}

function App() {
  return (
    <AAAAProvider>
      <BBBBProvider>
          Hello
      </BBBBProvider>
    </AAAAProvider>
  )
}
```

Comment: i dont have an answer because i didnt read the full question. but it sounds like if you use redux, and you have a reducer for each 'context', you can do as you please because you're pulling data from 1 source

Comment: I know it can be done with other state management libraries, I'm looking on how to do it specifically with React context

Comment: i can think of 2 possible options, but you'll have to experiment yourself to figure it out. 1) the parent action functions can accept a callback function, and you can pass a child action as the callback to execute (or pass the entire child context as an argument) 2) make a parent action that registers the child context, and when the child context loads/initializes, call the parent's register action and give it the child context and hold a reference to it. then you can call actions from that reference

Comment: I dont think the callback/argument method works. There's no access to neither the context or context action. If you know how to make it work please write it as answer with code example. But the second method might work, I added it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

One possible way is to store child context in the parent context, and every time the child context changes in useEffect, call a function in the parent to update the child context in the parent context.

```
import React, {useContext, createContext, useState, useEffect} from 'react'

const AAAAContext = createContext()
const BBBBContext = createContext()

function AAAAProvider(props) {
  const [bbbbActions, setBBBBActions] = useState()

  const aaaaActions = {
    doSomething: () => {
      bbbbActions.doSomething()
    },
    setBBBBActions
  }
  const aaaaContext = {aaaaActions}
  return <AAAAContext.Provider value={aaaaContext}>{props.children}</AAAAContext.Provider>
}

function BBBBProvider(props) {
  const aaaaContext = useContext(AAAAContext)

  const bbbbActions = {
    doSomething: () => {
      console.log('bbbbActions.doSomething')
    }
  }
  const bbbbContext = {bbbbActions}

  useEffect(() => {
    aaaaContext.aaaaActions.setBBBBActions(bbbbActions)
  }, [])

  return <BBBBContext.Provider value={bbbbContext}>{props.children}</BBBBContext.Provider>
}

function Component() {
  const aaaaContext = useContext(AAAAContext)
  window.aaaaContext = aaaaContext
  return 'Hello'
}

function App() {
  const aaaaContext = useContext(AAAAContext)
  window.aaaaContext = aaaaContext
  return (
    <AAAAProvider>
      <BBBBProvider>
        <Component/>
      </BBBBProvider>
    </AAAAProvider>
  )
}

export default App
```